Как отображать имена внутри события fullcalendar?
Видел на других сайтах возможность в fullcalendar отображать имена пользователей, к примеру кто забронировал комнату. (прикрепил скрин)
Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?


https://medevel.com/os-js-calendar/

@Dev18 лучше пояснить, что там по ссылке, вдруг кто-то по-английски не понимает.

Ничего полезного, спам ссылка.
